# Plot the graph of solution for a time period long.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains $100$ gal of water and $50$ oz of salt. Water containing a salt concentration of $\frac14[1+\frac12\sin t]$ oz/gal flows into the tank at a rate of $2$ gal/min, and the mixture in the tank flows out at the same rate.

(a) Find the amount of salt in the tank at any time.

(b) Plot the solution for a time period long enough so that you see the ultimate behavior of the graph.

I already find the solution for (a) which is

[$25+\frac{25}{5002}\sin t-\frac{625}{2501}\cos t+\frac{63150}{2501}e^{-0.02t}$]

and I plotted the graph but not sure correct or not. [image]

Comment: $\LaTeX$ **Tip:** Use \sin t ,\cos t and e^{-0.002t} to achieve $\sin t, \cos t$ and $e^{-0.002t}$

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I will improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $a)$

Let us take $Q(t)$ to be the amount of salt present in the tank at any time $t$. The salt enters the tank at a rate of $2\left[\dfrac14\left(1+\dfrac12\sin t\right)\right]=\dfrac12+\dfrac14\sin t\ \\ \dfrac{\mbox{ oz}}{\mbox{ min}}$

So, the differential equation governing the amount of salt in the tank at any given time is $$\dfrac{dQ}{dt}=\dfrac12+\dfrac14\sin t-\dfrac Q5$$

And the I.C $Q(0)=50$ oz. Now by solving the linear differential equation for $Q$ by using the I.F and I.C we get
$$Q(t)=25+\dfrac{1}{2501}[12.5\sin t-625\cos t+63150e^{-t/50}]$$

So, the amount of salt approaches the steady state, with an oscillation of amplitude $\dfrac14$ with level $25$ oz

For part$b)$

Your graph looks fine.

Comment: Hi, may I know how to get the oscillation of amplitude is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @LTY The amplitude of oscillation is about 
0.25, which we can see from the coefficient of the dominant oscillatory term in the solution.